# Guice - bind different instances based on enclosing class

Tags: java, guice

Is it possible to bind Named instance based on the enclosing class? For ex: in the below sample, classes A and B will get DataStore instance injected. However, I need to have primary store as StoreA and secondary store as StoreB in the scope/context of class A but primary store as StoreC and secondary store as StoreD in the scope/context of class B. How can this be achieved?

```
class A {
   @Inject
   public A(DataStore dataStore) {
      ... 
   }
}

class B {
   @Inject
   public B(DataStore dataStore) {
      ... 
   }
}

class DataStore {
   @Inject
   public A(@Named("primary") Store primaryStore, @Named("secondary") Store store) {
      ... 
   }
}

bind(Store.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("primary")).to(StoreA.class);//for class A
bind(Store.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("secondary")).to(StoreB.class);//for class A
bind(Store.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("primary")).to(StoreC.class);//for class B
bind(Store.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("secondary")).to(StoreD.class);//for class B
```

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes known as the ["robot legs" problem](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_build_two_similar_but_slightly_different_trees_of_objec), as if building a robot with identical legs but differing left and right feet. Each Leg to bind a Foot, but the Foot requested depends on the Leg requested. In your case, each DataStore binds to a primary and secondary Store, but which Stores depends on the DataStore requested.

A Guice-injected instance can't be bound directly based on its target (a [similar feature was rejected](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=27)), but [as mentioned in the FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_build_two_similar_but_slightly_different_trees_of_objec) you can use [`PrivateModule`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html) to create a similar effect.

```
install(new PrivateModule() {
  @Override public void configure() {
    bind(Store.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("primary")).to(StoreA.class);
    bind(Store.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("secondary")).to(StoreB.class);
    expose(A.class);
  }
});
install(new PrivateModule() {
  @Override public void configure() {
    bind(Store.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("primary")).to(StoreC.class);
    bind(Store.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("secondary")).to(StoreD.class);
    expose(B.class);
  }
});
```

Consequently, `@Named("primary") Store` will not be accessible outside of `A` or `B` (or its dependencies), but that makes sense; you're never defining a general `Store`, but `A` and `B` each have the private bindings they need.

(Disclaimer: I didn't get a chance to test this, so it may need refinement.)