# Guice inject based on scope

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

In my scenario I have a `BaseObject` which is an interface and then a `BaseObjectImpl`.

Then I have two clients, `ClientA` and `ClientB` which both reference `BaseObjectImpl` with the minor different being that the constructor argument to `BaseObjectImpl` should change depending on which client is using it. The setup looks like this:

`BaseObject`:

```
public interface BaseObject {
  void doAction();
}
```

BaseObjectImpl:

```
public class BaseObjectImpl implements BaseObject {
    @Inject
    public BaseObjectImpl(RandomInjectedObject random, String inputString) {
        this.inputString = inputString;
    }

    public void doAction() {
        // print input string
    }
```

Now for the clients:

ClientA:

```
public class ClientA {

    @Inject
    public ClientA(BaseObject baseObject) {
        this.baseObject = baseObject;
    }
```

ClientB:

```
public class ClientB {

    @Inject
    public ClientB(BaseObject baseObject) {
        this.baseObject = baseObject;
    }
```

Now the issue is that when inside my `ClientAModule` I want to provide the `inputString` argument such that it is set to `clientAString` and inside `ClientBModule` I want to provide `clientBString` instead.

What is the best way to go about doing this? Note that the BaseObjectImpl takes in two arguments (the other one has the same definition for both clients).

What I tried doing was inside the `BaseObjectModule` class that I have defined, I created a `Builder` inside which I could set a specific annotation and set a specific `inputString`. Then inside my `Client<AB>Module` I created a different `BindingAnnotation` in each of them. Then when I installed the `BaseObjectModule` I did so using the builder and each passed in their specific `BindingAnnotation` and `inputString`.

Then I try to bind the `BindingAnnotation` / `inputString` scope to a `Provider` for `BaseObject` is that I try to instantiate the `BaseObjectImpl` with the corresponding `inputString` and the injected `RandomInjectedObject` which I've provided also in the `BaseObjectModule`. I get an error saying:
`This Provider cannot be used until the Injector has been created` because I haven't created the injector inside the module itself.

I was looking at `AssistedInjection` so that I could make it so I just passed in the `inputString` at this time, but the problem is I still need the injector for that.

Comment: what do you mean when you say you still need the injector for assistedInjection?

Comment: https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html

In order to actually instantiate the class, you have to do:
@Inject private PaymentFactory paymentFactory;
paymentFactory.create()

Comment: Can you solve your problem using private modules as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554841/guice-bind-different-instances-based-on-enclosing-class)? (Also, be careful: `scope` has a technical meaning to dependency injection frameworks including Guice.)

Comment: I was able to solve it by simply making BaseObjectImpl take in providers instead of the actual values, and that way I can just pass in the providers inside the module